Marketing Cloud - Test journey and allow email send to multiple contacts
Journey Builder allows us to test the journey before activating it.
When setting up the journey test, we are presented with configuration options:

Choose contacts
Send Type
Test Behavior

In option 1, we select 5 contacts.
In option 2, we want all 5 contacts to receive email messages. However, the system only allows to send email to one email address. In other words, sending email messages to the selected contacts does not seem to be possible. Why?? How do you work around this design restriction?


